# Building xvidcap on Ubuntu 14.04 - undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'

Tags: 14.04, compiling, screencast

I'm trying to build xvidcap from sources on Ubuntu 14.04 since no package is available.
I've stumbled upon following error during make:

```
gcc -Wall -g -DDBUS_SERVICE_DIR=\""/usr/local/share/dbus-1/service"\" -g -O2 -pthread -I /home/jesper/xvidcap-1.1.7 -I/home/jesper/xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libavcodec -I/home/jesper/
xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libavformat -I/home/jesper/xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libavutil -I/home
/jesper/xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libswscale -I/home/jesper/xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libavdevice 
-export-dynamic -L/home/jesper/xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libavcodec -L/home/jesper/xvidcap-
1.1.7/ffmpeg/libavformat -L/home/jesper/xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libavutil -L/home/jesper
/xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libswscale -L/home/jesper/xvidcap-1.1.7/ffmpeg/libavdevice -o 
xvidcap app_data.o capture.o codecs.o colors.o frame.o gnome_frame.o gnome_ui.o 
gnome_warning.o gnome_options.o led_meter.o main.o options.o xtoffmpeg.o xtoxwd.o job.o 
xvc_error_item.o eggtrayicon.o  -pthread -lglade-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lxml2 -lgdk-x11-2.0 
-latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 
-lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lfreetype -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0    -Wl,-Bstatic -lavcodec 
-Wl,-Bdynamic -Wl,-Bstatic -lswscale -Wl,-Bdynamic -Wl,-Bstatic -lavutil -Wl,-Bdynamic  
-lm -lXdamage -lXfixes -lXmu 
/usr/bin/ld: frame.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: `LIBS="-lX11 -ldl -lXext -lz" ./configure`

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: @Seth: You're absolutely right. I first installed the following packages `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libglade2-dev libxmu-dev` then the proposed configure command. `make && sudo make install` did the rest. It's a valid answer. Apologies (and upvoted). Kudos to our moderators ;)